# Who is responsible for the precision?

Tags: algorithm, precision

Let's say some researchers have figured out a way to analyze data and they have developed an algorithm for that. At the time, the algorithm is described in a book, using lots of mathematical formulas.

Now the algorithm needs to be implemented in software. The developer can read the formulas and starts translating e.g. `Sum(f(x)) [1..n]` *(seems TeX is not allowed here)* to a `for` loop.

Depending on how the developer converts the formula into code, there might be overflows or truncation in floating point operations. Not knowing much about real-world input values, unit tests might not detect those issues. However, in some cases, this can be avoided just by re-ordering the items or simplifying terms.

**I wonder who is responsible for the precision of the output. Is it the mathematician or is it the developer?** The mathematician might not know enough about computer number formats while the developer might not know enough about mathematics to restructure the formula.

A simple example:

Given the [Binomial coefficient](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient) `n over k` which translates to `n! / (k! (n-k)!)`.

A simple implementation would probably use the factorial function and then input the numbers directly (pseudo code):

```
result = fac(n) / (fac(k) * fac(n-k))
```

This can lead to overflows for larger n. Knowing that, one could divide n! by k! first and do (pseudo code):

```
result = 1
for (i = k+1 to n) result *= i
result = result / fac(n-k)
```

which is a) faster because it needs less calculations and b) does not suffer from overflows.

Comment: Collaboration between mathematicians and programmers is key. And note that 13! overflows a 32 bit integer: not particularly large.

Comment: Your example has nothing to do with precision. Integers are precise, floating point numbers are not. There are precision problems inherent in numeric algorithms, while problems of integer size can always be solved by increasing integer size.

Comment: This is why, IMHO, a good programmer *must* have a strong basis in mathematics. It's one thing to drag-n-drop widgets around to create a GUI or something, it's an entirely different thing to be able to read a research paper on e.g. a new image compression algorithm and be able to correctly code something based on theoretical mathematical constructs, within the constraints of finite-precision hardware.

Comment: @n.m. I know, but I wanted to keep the example simple and understandable. The solution is the same, not matter it is precision or overflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This science is called `numerical analysis`

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_analysis

In my understanding the analysis is on the mathematician side, but it is the responsibility of the programmer to know the problem exists and to look for the correct well known solutions (like not using a simple Euler integrator but Runge-Kutta).

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: developer.

Algorithm (of just a formula) manipulates arbitrary precision real numbers as pure math objects.
Code (based on the formula) works with real hardware and must overcome limitations (which depends on your hardware) by using more complex code.

Example: Formula `f(x,y) = x * y` may lead to very complex source code (if x,y are 64-bit floating point real numbers and your hardware is 8-bit microcontroller without FPU support and without integer MUL instruction).